# android - php fetch mysql data by user id

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

This my PHP URL for fetching the data from MySQL. I need to make `mysqli_fetch_array` code saying if filled `uid` in the `app-data` table is the same with `uid` in `users` table fetch the data from all row in `app-data` to the `uid` like every user show his items from `app-data` table.

```
$host = "";
$user = "";
$pwd = "";
$db = ""; 

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM app_data ORDER By id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row; 
}

mysqli_close($con);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct answer:

```
<?php

$host = "";
$user = "";
$pwd = "";
$db = ""; 

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM app_data WHERE u_id=".$_POST['posted_uid']." ORDER By id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row; 
}

mysqli_close($con);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Little tip for the future:

Don't search exactly what you want, only search in parts.

Comment: first thanks so much for your answer ... and its not work with me because i want **$result** run normal .. all i want **while** go check with the **users** table if **app_empid** is the same in **app_empid**  in **app_data** table return fetching the **$result** normal so every user use my application see only his data in listview items

Comment: With `WHERE u_id` you select only the data from the specific user

Comment: sorry iam not understand ,, i don't have in my table `u_id`

Comment: With u_id mean i the column where the user id is stored

Comment: can i have something like this `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $uid = $_POST['uid'];
 $sql1 = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid'";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
 $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
    
 if($no_of_rows > 0){
     $row["result1"] = true;
    }else{
        $row["result1"] = false;
    }
    $rows[] = $row; 
}`

Comment: thanks its help me but my problem was not Passing parameters to php from the android when i pass it it's work with the **SELECT** thanks so much